# How to remove selected value copies in Dropdown list using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

There are a lot of examples how to do that, but what I want is different:

I want to keep the selected but remove the copies of selected item. So that dropdown list contains only selected value not other instances.

Here is the example:

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

This removes all instances of selected value:

```
$('#cars[value="volvo"]').remove();
```

But I need to keep the "Volvo" as selected.
Can someone help me?

Update: here is the figure:

[image]

as you can see we have double Volvo, can we keep only the selected one?

Comment: @CBroe wrote an answer previously: $('#cars option[value="volvo"]').not(':selected').remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is to remove the duplicated item of first option.

```js
$('#cars option[value="'+$('#cars').val()+'"]:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```